# Htaccess в подпапке

Tags: .htaccess

В подпапке сайта лежит htaccess, как с его помощью перенаправить все обращения к файлам в этой подпапке на index.php лежащий там же? Если можно с объяснением. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /имя_папки
RewriteRule     .*  index.php
```

Comment: После нескольких часов кореженья мозга о малоосмысленные статьи с непонятными прикладными задачами и по-мудацки написанными regexp'ами все встало на свои места, спасибо!